# Date Time range search in Laravel 5.6

Tags: jquery, html, laravel

I am displaying my data in a table. I have a signIn time in my tale. Now I want to **filter data between 2 dates**. I added jquery date time picker from date and to date. But I am confused to display only the date range data into the same table where by default showing all data. Can anyone please suggest me the exact way with model view and controller for date range filter?

**Date range input**

```
<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="input-group date form_meridian_datetime" data-date="2012-12-21T15:25:00Z">
    <input type="text" placeholder="from" name="from" id="from" size="16" class="form-control">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn default date-reset" type="button">
        <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
        </button>
        <button class="btn default date-set" type="button">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
        </button>
    </span>
</div>
```

**table**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="sample_3">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th> Permit Taker </th>
                <th> Permit By </th>
                <th> Permit Types </th>
                <th> Purpose </th>
                <th> Entry Date &Time </th>
                <th> Exit Date & Time </th>
                <th> SignIn </th>
                <th> SignOut </th>
                <th> Edit </th>
                <th> Delete </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach($internalVisitors as $internalVisitor)
            <tr>
                <td> {{ $internalVisitor->internalHosts->hostName }} </td>
                <td> {{ $internalVisitor->permitBy}} </td>
                <td> {{ $internalVisitor->permitType}} </td>
                <td> {{ $internalVisitor->purpose}} </td>
                <td> {{ $internalVisitor->startDate}} </td>
                <td> {{ $internalVisitor->endDate}} </td>

                <td>
                    @if ( $internalVisitor-> signIn === 1)
                    <span >{{ $internalVisitor->signInTime}}</span>
                    @else
                    <form method="post" action="{{route('signInUpdate','id')}}">
                        {{ csrf_field()}}
                        <input type="hidden" name="isSignIn" value="{{$internalVisitor->isSignIn}}"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="tableId" value="{{$internalVisitor->id}}"/>
                        <button type="submit">
                        <a >Sign In</a></button>

                    </form>
                    @endif
                </td>
                <td>

                    @if( $internalVisitor->signIn === 0)
                    <span>Not SignIn</span>

                    @elseif ($internalVisitor-> signIn === 1 && $internalVisitor->signOut === 1)
                    <span>{{ $internalVisitor->signOutTime}}</span>
                    @elseif($internalVisitor-> signIn === 1 && $internalVisitor->signOut === 0 )
                    <form method="post" action="{{route('signOutUpdate','id')}}">
                        {{ csrf_field()}}
                        <input type="hidden" name="signOut" value="{{$internalVisitor->signOut}}"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="tableId" value="{{$internalVisitor->id}}"/>
                        <button type="submit">

                    </form>
                    <a >Sign Out</a></button>

                    @endif
                </td>
                <td class=""><a class="btn btn-raised btn-primary btn-sm" href="{{ route('iVisitorEdit',
                $internalVisitor->id) }}"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form method="POST" id="delete-form-{{ $internalVisitor->id }}" action="{{ route('iVisitorDelete',$internalVisitor->id) }}" style="display: none;">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    {{ method_field('delete') }}

                </form>

                <button onclick="if(confirm('Are you Sure, You went to delete this?')){
                event.preventDefault();
                document.getElementById('delete-form-{{ $internalVisitor->id }}').submit();
                }else{
                event.preventDefault();
                }" class="btn btn-raised btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
            </td>

        </tr>
        @endforeach


    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Controller**

```
if (request()->has('from') && request()->has('to')) {
        $from = request()->get('from')->date('Y-m-d' . ' 00:00:00', time()); 
        $to = request()->get('to')->date('Y-m-d' . ' 00:00:00', time()); 

        $leads = InternalVisitor::whereBetween('signInTime', [$from, $to])->paginate(5);
        dd($leads);

    }
```

**script**

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.datepicker.setDefaults({
        dateFormat: 'Y-m-d H:i:s'
    });
    $(function(){
        $("#From").datepicker();
        $("#to").datepicker();
    });
    $('#range').click(function(){
        var From = $('#From').val();
        var to = $('#to').val();
        if(From != '' && to != '')
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: '{{route('internalVisitor')}}',
                method:"POST",
                data:{From:From, to:to},
                success:function(data)
                {
                    $('#sample_3').html(data);
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Please Select the Date");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to split your `from-to` range into two separate `where` conditions:

```php
use Carbon\Carbon;

...

$query = InternalVisitor::query();

if (request()->has('from')) {
    $from = Carbon::parse(request()->get('from'))->format('Y-m-d') . ' 00:00:00'; 
    $query->where('signInTime', '>=', $from);
}

if (request()->has('to')) {
    $to = Carbon::parse(request()->get('to'))->format('Y-m-d') . ' 23:59:59';
    $query->where('signInTime', '<=', $from);
}

$leads = $query->paginate(5);
```

Comment: It's showing now "FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)
Call to a member function date() on string"

Comment: I just copy-pasted your code assuming it was working. You can use `Carbon` to parse incoming string datetime values. I updated the answer.

Comment: I used Carbon but it's showing me "DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (27 August 2018 - 05:28 PM) at position 15 (-): Unexpected character"

Comment: Now that I looked into your code, your datetime pickers are using "Y-m-d H:i:s" format, so you can directly feed it into your queries: `$query->where('signInTime', '>=', request()->get('from'));`